# Promises and async functions "borrowing" variables from concurrently running promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, waterline

I have this Waterline async call inside helper function answerUserTag:

```
theQuestion = await UserTag.findOne({id: answerObject.tag});
```

This is how I call the above helper:

```
const promises = userTagAnswers.map(userTagAnswer =>
  sails.helpers.answerUserTag.with(
    {
      userTagAnswer: userTagAnswer,
      answeringUserId: inputs.userId,
      userType: inputs.userType
    }));

await Promise.all(promises);
```

If there's just one userTagAnswers (i.e. one promise), it works fine. But if there's two userTagAnswers and I set a breakpoint after the `theQuestion` query in the helper, I see the following non-sensible values:

> `answerObject.tag` is equaled to `5c338ae267a1983e84340388`
>
> `theQuestion.id` is equaled to `5c27227ac1e60913703f3002`

It seems like there's an illogical overlap between variables when multiple promises are called.

Comment: Is your helper returning a promise?
this may help: https://toniov.github.io/p-iteration/

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug it through `Promise.each()` perhaps? Since the iteration is sequential, you'll know which Promise is troubling you.

Secondly, it would be great if you specify the helper function.

Thirdly, why `with`? If you check [MDN - with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), it clearly states *and I quote*:

> Use of the `with` statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. It has Ambiguity contra. The `with` statement makes it hard for a human reader or JavaScript compiler to decide whether an unqualified name will be found along the scope chain, and if so, in which object.

Comment: using Promise.each() 'solved' the problem as in there are no errors and the function runs as it's supposed to, but I'd like to figure out how to run them all concurrently.

Comment: OP does not use a `with` statement, he uses a method called `.with()`.

Comment: That's a quote from MDN. But yes, tell me if they're different.

Answer (score 0):

The inconsistant results are because the promises are resolving async

this may help: toniov.github.io/p-iteration